# Is there a way to select a specific class having a specific inner value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

for example, there are 6 "p" tags in a div having the same class but some "p" tags have member text inside while some have non-members. I want to select all the "p" tags with "member" inner text and add another class to them using jquery

This is the code i want to perform action on

```
<div>
<p class="customClass">Member</p>
<p class="customClass">Non-Member</p>
<p class="customClass">Member</p>
<p class="customClass">Non-Member</p>
<p class="customClass">Member</p>
</div>
```

This is the expected result

```
<div>
<p class="customClass member">Member</p>
<p class="customClass">Non-Member</p>
<p class="customClass member">Member</p>
<p class="customClass">Non-Member</p>
<p class="customClass member">Member</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the jquery selector $("p:contains(Member)") ?

Comment: yes I tried it but it also adds class to the Non-Member as it also contains the term Member in it

Comment: Check my answer, the solution is there.  $(".customClass p:not(:contains(Non-Member))").addClass("member")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `filter` all `.customClass` that only contains "Members" and add class `.member`

```js
$(".customClass").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === "Member"
}).addClass("member");
```

```css
.member {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="customClass">Member</p>
  <p class="customClass">Non-Member</p>
  <p class="customClass">Member</p>
  <p class="customClass">Non-Member</p>
  <p class="customClass">Member</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Man! kindly just tell me one more thing that. how can run this script if the content of  the parent div changes or more elements are added to those div

Comment: You can put the code on a function. Call the function every update is one option. The other one is, add already the class before updating the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write the selector like this:

```js
$(".member").exampleMethod();
```

this is a selector by class, is a very simple and basic solution so I recommend you to read the jquery documentation

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
    $("p:contains(Member)")
```

This will return all 'p' tags containing the text 'Member'.  Then assign additional class with:

```
    $("p:contains(Member)").addClass("member");
```

If you only want the "Members" and not to include the "Non-Members" use:

```
    $("p:not(:contains(Non-Member))").addClass("member")
```

You could make this more specific by adding more to the selector text.  I haven't tried this but play around with:

```
    $(".customClass p:not(:contains(Non-Member))").addClass("member")
```

To select all tags with the class "customClass" and NOT containing the text Non-Member.  Just edited, now it selects all "p" tags with the class "customClass" NOT containing the text "Non-Member", then adds the additional class "member" to those.

Comment: Addition to answer: `$("p:contains(Member)").addClass('member')`